# C++17 split constexpr string on comma and have the number of elements at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++17, metaprogramming

I have a comma-separated list of fields represented by a char array at compile time:

`constexpr static char arrayStr[] = "a,b,c";`

I would like to split on "," and have the number of elements available at compile time. Pseudo code:

`constexpr static size_t numFields = SPLIT(arrayStr, ",");`

would return 3.

Is there any way to achieve this using C++17?

Comment: Just count the ',' in a constexpr function. Easy in C++17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a templated function that accepts a fixed length array by reference, templated on the length of the array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

constexpr char arrayStr[] = "a,b,c";

template<size_t N>
constexpr size_t numFields(const char(&arrayStr)[N], char delim) {
    size_t count = 1;
    for (const auto& ch : arrayStr) {
        if (ch == delim) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    array<string,numFields(arrayStr,',')> x;
    cout << x.size() << endl;
}
```

Templating arrows arrayStr to be a fixed-size array argument, allowing the range-based for loop.

**EDIT**

The OP asked in the comments about creating a class at compile time whose members include the string literal and its tokenization count (something was also mentioned about static class members, but I'm not clear on the use case). This was trickier! After some work, the above `numFields` function can be used together with something like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template<typename T>
    constexpr Foo(T&& str, char delim)
    : _array(std::forward<T>(str)),
      _count(numFields(_array,delim)) {
    }

    auto data() const {
        return _array;
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return _count;
    }

private:
    const char (&_array)[N];
    const size_t _count;
};


template<typename T>
constexpr auto wrapArray(T&& str, char delim) -> Foo<sizeof(str)> {
    return Foo<sizeof(str)>(std::forward<T>(str),delim);
}

constexpr auto wrappedArrayStr = wrapArray("a,b,c",',');

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << wrappedArrayStr.size() << endl;
    cout << wrappedArrayStr.data() << endl;
}
```

I'm not certain that the perfect forwarding here is necessary, but I use it to forward the string literal argument to the class member. The helper function `wrapArray` prevents having to double-paste all the compile time string literals, i.e. avoiding `constexpr Foo<sizeof("a,b,c")> wrappedArrayStr("a,b,c",',');`.

Comment: Does this allow a constexpr static size_t class member though?

Comment: @user997112 Not sure what you mean? The return value is constexpr size_t, and the use in the std::array proves that.

Comment: This is giving compiler errors saying numFields cannot be used as a constant expression. arrayStr and the number of elements are both class members of the same class?

Comment: @user997112 What does your class constructor look like?

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to convert the char array to string, then split on "," and have the number of elements available at compile time.

If for "string" do you mean "`std::string`", it isn't `constexpr` so it's incompatible with a compile time computation.

If for "string" you accept the C-style string, a `char const *`, and if you're interested in separators of a single `char`, you can try something as follows

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr static char arrayStr[] = "a,b,c";

constexpr std::size_t SPLIT (char const * str, char sep)
 {
   std::size_t  ret { 1u };

   while ( *str )
      if ( sep == *str++ )
         ++ ret;

   return ret;
 }

int main ()
 {
   constexpr auto numFields = SPLIT(arrayStr, ',');

   std::cout << numFields << std::endl;  // print 3
 }
```

Comment: When I assign SPLIT() to numFields I get "constexpr variable 'numFields' must be initialized by a constant expression"

Comment: @user997112 - I don't know where is your problem... the code in my answer compile with both g++ (8.3.0) and clang++ (7.0.1). You're compiling my exact code? Which compiler are you using? Are you compiling C++17 ? (but C++14 should be enough)

Comment: Can you put these in a class, create a new member: constexpr static size_t numElements = SPLIT(arrayStr, ',');

Comment: @user997112 - why not? `class foo
 { public: static constexpr auto bar = SPLIT(arrayStr, ','); };`

Comment: I used the other answer, but i've given you three upvotes because you did reply first